# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: detected a hanging thread 'QEMU2 CPU0 thread'. No response for 15000 ms

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I try all ways but it not solved. 
I try to  choose quick boot instead of cold boot but I am using linux.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Share with us your pc specs!

Comment: @G.Ciardini, what is not specific to you here? That's the error message she is receiving when trying to launch Android emulator.